# inbound sftp channel adapter file locking issue

Tags: spring-integration

I am using sftp inbound channel adapter with custom remote filter. If filter accept that file then it is processed later and deleted fine as i set property "true" for remote delete.

Now when my file is not processed successfully and throws exception then i catch that exception and want to move locally download file to someother place but when i do that using FileUtils.forceDelete then it is throwing exception

java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file:

Looks like some other thread has lock on this file. Is there any way we can find out who owns the lock and how to release it so that my listener can move it to diff location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not processed successfully and throws exception

Be sure to close the file in a finally block so your processing logic will always close the file.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I was closing all streams except one. Here is how my code looked like 
      zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFileName)); now i was closing zis but not fileinputstream. So I created local varible for FIS and close that first and then ZIS and it solved the problem. I also used windows tool while debugging code to find out which line of code was locking it.